# ServiceStack.Swagger doesn't work with ServiceStack.Razor

Tags: razor, servicestack, swagger

I've been playing with ServiceStack lib's for a couple of weeks and seems found an issue.
When I download an [example project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/SwaggerHelloWorld) for Swagger-UI from github everything works just fine until I add RazorFormat feature. Then I get "Handler for Request not found" error when trying to view ***localhost:50001/swagger-ui/index.html*** (which was previously working).

So how to use both: swagger and razor?
I tried to rename index.html to index.cshtml to make razor engine deal with this file. The page was working but no JS, and no CSS downloaded, so it wasn't useful much.